# How to say phone numbers

Tags: spelling, speaking, telephone-conversation

In my textbook I read that in German you can say phone numbers in single digits

> 7-6-2-8-3-9-etc. (sieben-sechs-zwei/zwo-acht-drei-neun-etc.)

or in pairs

> 76-28-39-etc. (sechsundsiebzig-achtundzwanzig-neununddreißig-etc.)

I am wondering if there is any preference upon either way or they are equivalently applied.

Comment: From my personal experience I encountered both version. But I personally prefer the single digit version, because the two digit numbers in German are (mostly) pronounced 'the other way round'. 21 is literally 'one-and-twenty'.